# How to record digital piano through a wired usb a to b connection?

Tags: recording, digital-piano, audio

I have a Yamaha Clavinova CLP-625 digital piano. I have recorded it onto the piano so I can listen to it by pressing play. I want to get a good audio recording my laptop so I can upload it. All I have is a USB cable which is connected from the piano to the computer how can I record only sound from the piano so that there is no background noise?

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual for [computer-related operations](https://usa.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/4/329494/computer_en_rm_m0.pdf):

> You can record your keyboard performance as audio data to a Music Production software on your computer. For more detailed instructions, refer to the Owner’s Manual supplied with your instrument.To transmit audio data, you will need to install the Yamaha Steinberg USB Driver to your computer.

In addition, you'll also need a DAW which will probably see the clavinova as an "external sound card", from which it is possible to record. It is possible that with standard DAWs (like Audacity for instance), the piano will be seen as such device straight away but hard to be sure without trying!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link provided by @TomC I scrolled to the bottom and it says your particular model unfortunately only transmits and receives MIDI data, not audio so you will have to take another approach.

The simplest (and cheapest) approach is to send a line from the headphone output of the keyboard to the computer’s microphone input. You may need to buy a cable and adapter to do this. Then you can use any DAW to record the audio from your piano. Your computer probably even has a very basic audio recorder installed. Use the volume control on the instrument to make sure the piano is not distorting when recording. You will be using your computer’s built in audio card so the sound won’t be the best but it should be decent.

Comment: Haha, should have more carefully! I was actually surprised that a digital piano was able to transmit sound through USB...

Comment: @Tom_C It was on the last page, I didn’t know any of them had that capability either!